# Finding text in element with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am wanting to state whether this text 'Awaiting Review' is true or not. How do I find this element? With all the parent elements im struggling to get it. If someone could elaborate on how it works that would be amazing.
[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page? What do you mean by `I am wanting to state whether this text 'Awaiting Review' is true or not`? Are you trying to find if there is an element with text "Awaiting Review" on the page or if that specific element inside it's parent elements having this text?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in DevTools, you can right click and select 'Copy XPath'. This will give you a specific and unique selector for the element so you don't need to worry about counting parent divs all the way from the root! Learning XPaths is a great tool, see here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Then in your Selenium code you can write:

```
awaiting_review = driver.find_element_by_xpath('# paste xpath here').text

if awaiting_review == 'Awaiting Review':
   # whatever you want to happen
```

Comment: if the element is not found by the xpath, it will throw `NoSuchElement` exception

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**  :- with `//span[contains(text(), 'Awaiting Review')]` you can located the element and can check if the `size if > 0` using `find_elements`, if it is, then you can assert, (I am just using print) and if it's not, code will go to else part.

You can try with below **code** :

```
try:
   if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Awaiting Review')]")) > 0 :
       print("Awaiting Review is present")
   else:
        print("Awaiting Review is not present")
except:
    print("something went wrong. ")
    pass
```

**Update 1 :**

```
try:
   if len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#air-pipeline-board heade.air-pipeline-lane span")) > 0 :
       print("Awaiting Review is present")
   else:
        print("Awaiting Review is not present")
except:
    print("something went wrong. ")
    pass
```

Comment: I tried this, but its saying 'awaiting review is not present' so its not finding the right element. @cruisepandey

Comment: meaning it could not find it on UI, Are you sure that it's present in UI  ?

Comment: Yeah it is definitely there.

Comment: okay is the Page URL public ? can you share ?

Comment: I have even given solution with different locator, can you try that updated 1 code  ?

Comment: The page in not public.. Ive tried the updated one, but its still not finding the saying 'Awaiting Review is not present'

Comment: Can you check if it's in iframe ? meanwhile can you do this `print(driver.page_source)`, and share the html code with us

Comment: I think it is an iframe because when I print the page source i cant find awaiting review anywhere.

Comment: okay in that case, `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('iframe xpath here'))` you can switch it like this. and then you can use the above solution to see if it's printing the right thing or not

Answer (score 0):

To simply validate if element containing that text exists on the page you can do this:

```
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Awaiting Review')]"):
    print("Element is presented")
else:
    print("Eelement not found")
```

`driver.find_elements` returns a list of elements matching the passed locator.
So if there is a `span` element containing `Awaiting Review` text is presented on the page it will return it. Otherwise it will return an empty list.
Non-empty list is seen as `True` by Python while empty list is `False`.

Comment: Is there a difference between [if self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath] and [if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH] ?

Comment: @AndrewReiblein are you asking about the `self` before or `(By.XPATH)` after the `driver.find_elements`?

Comment: No, only the (by_xpath) and (By.XPATH). Thank you

Comment: As cruisepandey said no. I usually use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#vacancy-pipeline-header>header>div>span")
if elems:
   if elems[0].text == "Awaiting Review":
     print('valid!')
   else 
     print('invalid!')
else
  print('Element is not exist!')
```

If you are familiar with CSS selector, it's good for you.